# I think I deleted grub bootloader

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, grub-efi

I have a dual boot system with Windows 10. This morning, I formatted an external hard drive via Mini Tool Partition on Windows and powered off my PC. But now I can't boot into Ubuntu. I can boot in Windows fine. I checked on the BIOS/Boot Menu. Only Windows Boot Manager was there. I can access the root partition via the Linux File System on Windows.
Here is what my Boot Drive looks like

[image: Boot Drive]

Is there a way to install the GRUB Bootloader?

Comment: Use the `boot-repair` app. See:    https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of googling and with the help of a Redditor, I was finally able to boot to Ubuntu. Here are the steps I followed -

1. Boot into a live session.
2. Use the `lsblk`, `sudo fdisk -l` commands, or GParted to know which partition is used for Ubuntu. In my case partition /dev/nvme0n1p5 is used for OS.
3. Use these commands to mount-

```
sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /media
sudo mount --bind /dev /media/dev
sudo mount --bind /sys /media/sys
sudo mount --bind /proc /media/proc
```

4. Then chroot the media `sudo chroot /media`
5. Finally, install the grub by using the command `sudo grub-install /dev/nvme0n1`. Use only the device name, not the partition.
   *This should work for most of the people. But I got an error `grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory`
6. All I have to do is mount the EFI partition to the /boot/efi `sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /boot/efi/`
7. Then use the grub-install command again.